# How to create shortcut to solutions folder or file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

Structure of project on which I am working right now is very bad. Is there any possibility to create shortcuts in Visual Studio 2012 for files and folders as in windows explorer.

I would like to have shortcuts to frequently used folders and files.

Comment: Please don't use [productivity] tag. See http://productivity.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for that problem is just adding new solution folder. And then drag and drop files to that folder, they will automatically become shortcuts. Unfortunately, I don't find solution for creating shortcuts for folders.

[image: Files shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

Put those files in a shared project and reference that or add it to your other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a shortcut solution folder can be done as follows:

- Right-click on the .csproj file, and choose *Edit Project File*
- Add an entry like this

...

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="any_abs_or_rel_path\**\*.*">
        <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120719043826/http://greenicicleblog.com/2010/12/01/link-whole-directories-into-visual-studio-projects) gives more details.